# Word VBA to refresh embedded Excel chart

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have embedded charts in a Word doc. When I update the data in Excel, so that the chart in the Excel workbook updates, and then go to the Word doc, I can manually select the embedded chart, select Design > Refresh Data, and the embedded chart in Word updates to show the new data.

When I try to record the Word VBA to do that, it won't let me do those actions.

I've looked everywhere I can think of in Word's object browser. I see that I can identify the embedded chart like this:

```
thisdocument.InlineShapes(1)
```

But I don't see how to refresh it. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-msoffice_custom/what-is-the-vba-equivalent-of-refresh-data-for/b8405aca-716a-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5

```
thisdocument.InlineShapes(1).LinkFormat.Update
```

It worked fine in my tests.

And to break the link (in the word template) after updating, to avoid inadvertently updating the chart to one from a later run showing different data:

```
thisdocument.InlineShapes(1).LinkFormat.BreakLink
```