# refresh word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a VBA Script which I found online to save multiple Word `datasets` as `"Serienbrief"` (I think it is called bulkletter in english) in a PDF format.
The word document consists of various `Mergefields` as well as multiple Excel bar graphs, which are still connected to the according Excel file.

**Problem:**

When I save the `datasets` as `pdf`, the `mergefields` change when the `dataset` changes.

The graphs however, have always the values of the first `dataset`. I can update the graph to the correct values by refreshing the Word document manually after changing the `dataset`, but I'd need to automate the process.

**What I am looking for:**

I would need to extend the Script below, that it refreshes the Document (and therefore also the bar graphs) every time before it saves a new `pdf` (basically `cntrl+A` and then `F9`).

**What I have tried:**

I found a similar question here [Word VBA to refresh embedded Excel chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895647/word-vba-to-refresh-embedded-excel-chart), but the answer didn't help me, also because I am not sure where to implement it in the script.

Below you find the script which I used so far and which works pretty fine, except of the missing refresh- part.

Any help is appreciated!

```
Sub Serienbrief()
' set variables
Dim iBrief As Integer, sBrief As String
Dim AppShell As Object
Dim BrowseDir As Variant
Dim Path As String
' catch any errors
On Error GoTo ErrorHandling

' determine path
Set AppShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set BrowseDir = AppShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Speicherort für Serienbriefe auswählen", 0, 16)

If BrowseDir = "Desktop" Then
Path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
Else
Path = BrowseDir.items().Item().Path
End If

If Path = "" Then GoTo ErrorHandling

Path = Path & "\Serienbrief-" & Format(Now, "dd.mm.yyyy-hh.mm.ss") & "\"
MkDir Path

On Error GoTo ErrorHandling

' hide application for better performance
MsgBox "Serienbriefe werden exportiert. Dieser Vorganag kann einige Minuten dauern - Microsoft Word wird während dieser Zeit ausgeblendet", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
Application.Visible = False

' create bulkletter and export as pdf
With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
.DataSource.ActiveRecord = 1
Do
.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
.SuppressBlankLines = True



With .DataSource
.FirstRecord = .ActiveRecord
.LastRecord = .ActiveRecord
sBrief = Path & .DataFields("IDSCHOOL").Value & ".pdf"
End With
.Execute Pause:=False
ThisDocument.InlineShapes(1).LinkFormat.BreakLink

If .DataSource.DataFields("IDSCHOOL").Value > "" Then
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=sBrief, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
End If
ActiveDocument.Close False

If .DataSource.ActiveRecord < .DataSource.RecordCount Then
.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord
Else
Exit Do
End If
Loop
End With

' error handling
ErrorHandling:
Application.Visible = True

If Err.Number = 76 Then
MsgBox "Der ausgewählte Speicherort ist ungültig", vbOKOnly + vbCritical
ElseIf Err.Number = 5852 Then
MsgBox "Das Dokument ist kein Serienbrief"
ElseIf Err.Number = 4198 Then
MsgBox "Der ausgewählte Speicherort ist ungültig", vbOKOnly + vbCritical
ElseIf Err.Number = 91 Then
MsgBox "Exportieren von Serienbriefen abgebrochen", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation
ElseIf Err.Number > 0 Then
MsgBox "Unbekannter Fehler: " & Err.Number & " - Bitte Makro erneut ausführen.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical
Else
MsgBox "Serienbriefe erfolgreich exportiert", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share the document?

Comment: Sure, is a screenshot enough or would you like the whole document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
ThisDocument.InlineShapes(1).LinkFormat.BreakLink
```

to:

```
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).LinkFormat.Update
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).LinkFormat.BreakLink
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the code, the Merge Fields changed, but unfortunately the graphs stayed the same (with the values of the first data set). Is the line ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).LinkFormat.BreakLink placed on the correct line (see OP)?

Comment: Since that line occurs after '.Execute Pause:=False', yes. At a more basic level, though, I can't see anything in your code that tells Word where to look for the chart data. Simply executing the mailmerge doesn't address that.

Comment: I basically took a Mailmerge field called ID, which is the identifier for one dataset. I copied this ID from the Word document to an Excel file and than used vlookup to gather the data for a graph and copied that grapgh back to the Word document. So whenever I change the dataset in word, the excel file with the graph changes the data (because of vlookup) and therefore the graph changes as well. So I thought the graphs would change automatically, if I intergrate a code which refreshes the page after each dataset.

Comment: I can't see anything in the code you posted to do that. Regardless, ThisDocument.InlineShapes(1).LinkFormat.BreakLink breaks the link immediately the first record is merged, preventing any further updates. That's why ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).LinkFormat.BreakLink *after* the merge - and *after* the lookup and the link have been updated - is what is required. Just to make sure the link update happens it's best to force it to occur. See revised answer.